# Do we really need locking when are caching in asp.net mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, locking, httpcontext

I saw many caching examples that include locking.I am trying to cache common list for entire application.Do I really need to use locks like below ? The worst thing can happen if I don't use locking is that ;

If multiple threads  detect a cache miss at about the same time.They might attempt to load data simultaneously.In conclusion , data will be the same...

Is it true ?

```
 public class Worker

{

    private static object someLock;

    public static object CacheMethod()
    {

        var results = HttpContext.Current.Cache["Common"];

        if (results == null)
        {
            lock (someLock)
            {
                results = HttpContext.Current.Cache["Common"];
                if (results == null)
                {
                    results = GetResultsFromSomewhere();
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("Common", results, null,
                            DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                }
            }
        }
        return results;

    }``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lock is used to prevent cache stampeding. If the cache is empty and takes a while to fill then all incoming requests will start to fill the cache. Depending on how the numbers work out that can be a catastrophic loss of performance.

If `GetResultsFromSomewhere` was `Thread.Sleep(10000)` then this could easily happen.

The bad thing about that particular code is that it's one lock for all cache keys. Usually you want one lock per key.

Comment: If I don't use locking the scenario will be like that ;                                           If user A request sees this cache null , it will call GetResultsFromSomewhere which takes 10 seconds to complete.In the mean time user B  does the same thing and waits 10 seconds.. But I use locking the scenario will be like that ; User A grabs the lock and User B will wait for that lock to be released.It will approximately wait 10 seconds again .. so it seems to me that there won't be so much performance loss.. Am I wrong ?

Comment: "In the mean time user B does the same thing and waits 10 seconds" No, user B also calls GetResultsFromSomewhere. We now have two such calls at the same time and twice the resource usage. Why do you think user B would wait?

Comment: I tried to say that user B will call GetResultsFromSomewhere and wait for the operation to return a result and it will again take 10 seconds.If I use locking than this time user B wait for User A to release the lock and this will take 10 seconds again.Somehow ,User B wait approximately 10 seconds.In my mind,there is not so much difference between caching with lock and without lock.Is there ?

Comment: Hm maybe I understand what you mean. Indeed, the waiting time is 10sec but in case of using a lock only one resource call will be made. That causes less load. If you make 1000 queries to your database taking 10sec each that server is completely overloaded, times out, and causes unavailability for the rest of the website as well.

Comment: I got you what you mean..Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [double-checked locking pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). Yes, it is true that if you have many requests and the data takes longer to retrieve than the time between requests, you could have multiple requests for the same data.

Without the locking, each additional thread is receiving the same data so the amount of CPU/Network Activity/RAM used by the additional threads is just wasted. Whether or not this is a problem depends on how much traffic your site has and the available server/network resources.

However, it is much more important to ensure that your `results` object itself is thread-safe, because you are guaranteed to have multiple threads interacting with its state. The simplest way is just to make all of its properties read-only, but if you need writable properties you could use a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) in conjunction with methods that ensure atomic actions (see the examples in the link).